# Avoid .change() event to be fired at document.ready

Tags: jquery, linked-list, onchange, dynamic-data, document-ready

I have an agencies DB. Each agency has (among others) 3 chained selects with dynamic/ajax options:
- country
- state
- location

When adding an agency: If user changes country select, its `.change()` event fires and loads the states for that country in 'state' select, and so on.

When user modifies an agency's info/data a problem rises. I load (with php) current agency's country, state and location in respective selects, but when `(document).ready` fires, the selects are changed.

**Although I want to keep the dynamics of `change` event working for each of the dynamic chained selects, How could I do to avoid that `.change()` being fired at `(document).ready`? I mean, "first time" event fires**

The code for chained selects
http://jsfiddle.net/LWPVm/

Maybe another idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can we see your Javascript code?? Because it shouldn't fire the change event on load?

Comment: attach event handlers after updating `select` in `doucment.ready`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LWPVm/

Comment: LOL, solved by removing last .change() in each select's .change event, that forced each select to fire the change event at document.ready. See jsfiddle. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this problem by removing the last .change(); call in each function.
This .change forced to fire the event at (document).ready . I now remember I needed so the chained selects work fine. Hope this can be useful for someone else.

```
jQuery('#selProvincia').change(function(){
var val = this.value;
jQuery.post('<?php echo site_url("funciones_ajax/obtener_departamentos"); ?>/'+val, 
    {  },
    function(data) {
        var sel = jQuery("#selDepartamento");
        sel.empty();
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            sel.append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].nombre + '</option>');
        }
    }, "json"); }).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).load(function(){
   $db.change(function(){
      event.stoppropagation();
});
```

will stop the propagation. should work while page is loading. be careful not to call this function while document.ready() as then the propagation will be stopped overall, you could also use:

```
$db.change(function(){
   event.preventDefault();
});
```